# Micronaut Hibernate Reactive: Issues with 'findAllBy' when using a property whose name is a part of another property's name

Tags: jpa, repository-pattern, micronaut, micronaut-data, hibernate-reactive

I'm writing a new version of a Service previously written using Spring Boot using micronaut, and currently I'm porting existing entities and I have come across this issue, seems that ReactorCrudRepository misbehaves when I have a property whose name is part of another property's name.

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class UserGroupMembership {

    @Id
    private Long uid;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private UserGroup userGroup;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User user;

}
```

```
@Entity 
@Data 
public class UserGroup {

@Id
private Long uid;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="userGroup", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<UserGroupMembership> userAuthorizations = new HashSet<UserGroupMembership>();

@ManyToOne
private Area area;

}
```

```
@Entity 
@Data 
public class Area {
    
    @Id
    private Long uid;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Area parent;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment;
    
}
```

And the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserGroupMembershipRepository extends ReactiveStreamsCrudRepository<UserGroupMembership, Long> {

    Flux<UserGroupMembership> findAllByUserLogin(String login);
    
    
    @Join(value = "userGroup.area", type = Join.Type.FETCH)
    Flux<UserGroupMembership> findAllByUserLoginAndUserGroupAreaUid(String login, Long uid);

}
```

When compiling it seems that it fails to understand that I want the Area UID associated with the UserGroup, instead it tries to find a property UserGroupAreaUid, which doesn't exist.
`java: Unable to implement Repository method: UserGroupMembershipRepository.findAllByUserLoginAndUserGroupAreaUid(String login,Long uid). Cannot query entity [UserGroupMembership] on non-existent property: UserGroupAreaUid`

I tried defining the findAllBy method as findAllByUserLoginAndUserGroup_AreaUid(String login,Long uid) but no help: `java: Unable to implement Repository method: UserGroupMembershipRepository.findAllByUserLoginAndUserGroup_AreaUid(String login,Long uid). Cannot query entity [UserGroupMembership] on non-existent property: UserGroup_AreaUid`

What did the trick was exchanging `private User user;` in my UserGroupMembership entity for `private User member;` and then changing the findAllBy definition accordingly: `findAllByMemberLoginAndUserGroupAreaUid(String login, Long uid)`

That works, but I really would like to keep the former property names since they are entities defined ages ago and people are really used to them. Is this a bug with Micronaut's reactive repositories or is there any way around it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was indeed a bug, per issue https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues/2474

As suggested, one should use an underscore to avoid ambiguity:

```
@Join(value = "userGroup.area", type = Join.Type.FETCH)
Flux<UserGroupMembership> findAllByUserLoginAndUserGroup_AreaUid(String login, Long uid);
```

Reference: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/data/1.0/data-1.0.0-b3#_entity_property_names